# How to load html data into a existing html page

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a html page with a drop down menu that displays a list when a drop down is selected. I can create the list in a text file or plain html file.

For example, use selected product name - then a list displays of vendors subscriber to the product, then user selects another drop down and another list of data replaces what was displaying in the browser. I hope I am explaining this properly.

Comment: Please add a minimum verifiable example so that the community can reproduce your question. Let us know what you have tried and put some code in your question.Just trying to help :)

Comment: There are many questions about this on this site and others. I suggest copying your title and pasting it into a search engine and read the results.

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to ask a proper question please.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these Bootstrap components:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/dropdowns/

Copy paste the code to your HTML file and change the text in whatever way you like!